# Est-il correct de laisser tomber le « il » dans « il y a » ?

Tags: usage, grammaire, argot, oral

On voit souvent l'abandon du *il* dans la phrase *il y a…*, tant dans l'écriture formelle que dans l'écriture informelle, et aussi dans le discours.
Exemple:

> Y a des chiens…

Est-ce que c'est acceptable de laisser tomber le *il*, ou est-ce que c'est encore considéré comme de l'argot de le faire ?

Comment: Coworkers make fun of me because I do it all the time. :'(

Comment: Un exemple tout ce qu'il y a d'officiel, puisqu'évoqué chaque 14 juillet devant le Président de la République Française: "Pour les Belges, Y en a plus"

Comment: Il faut signaler la chanson de Trenet [Y'a d'la joie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27a_d%27la_joie), chanson célèbre, en France, en tous cas.

Comment: De toutes façons, y'a pas photo, ça finira bien par devenir correct un jour.

Comment: Ce serait [en principe](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/il-y-a-y-a-ya/) « Y a », mais on trouve fréquemment « Y'a ».

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Non. À l'oral cette séquence de trois mots est très souvent abrégée, mais l'écriture doit rester « il y a ».

Les raccourcis « Ya », « 'ya », « y a » apparaîtront sûrement dans des salons de discussion ou autres supports informels. Cela n'apparaîtra jamais dans un livre, excepté peut-être dans une citation orale, ou dans une bande dessinée.

Answer (score 12):

C'est un emploi **accepté** en français informel (écrit et parlé), mais plutôt mal vu en français standard (surtout à l'écrit).

Answer (score 11):

Cet usage est parfaitement **incorrect** dans un langage formel (à l'écrit en particulier).

Son seul usage à l'écrit est réservé à accentuer le caractère argotique des paroles (par exemple pour mettre l'accent sur le milieu social d'un personnage).

Answer (score 5):

La phrase :

```
Y a des chiens dans la rue.
```

est **incorrecte**.

L'abandon du pronom *il* reflète un raccourci oral très répandu mais n'est pas grammaticalement correct.

Comment: -1 pour prescriptivisme. Si une locution est "très répandue" chez les gens ayant le français comme langue maternelle, elle est par définition grammaticalement correcte. Sinon, on devrait parler le latin, et non le français! Tu peux dire que cet usage n'est pas accepté à l'écrit ou dans les discours formels, mais dire que c'est "incorrect" n'a pas de sens.

Comment: De toutes façons ce sont des chats.

Comment: @Brennan, haha, que [la guerre](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist) commence :)

Comment: @Brennan Vincent: L'usage, aussi répandu soit-il, ne change pas les règles de grammaire. Si c'était le cas, des propositions comme *Si j'aurais su* devraient être acceptées comme grammaticalement correctes.

Comment: @Laurent: Oh que si! Sinon, comme je l'ai dit plus haut, pourquoi ne parles-tu pas latin? Mais on devrait en discuter sur le site meta et pas ici.

Comment: @LaurentPireyn Oui, l'expression *Si j'aurais su* deviendrait correcte si elle devenait d'usage courant assez longtemps et prenait le pas sur l'actuel *Si j'avais su*.

Comment: On peut le déplorer, mais c'est l'Académie Française qui décide de ce qui est grammaticalement correct dans la langue française. L'intégration des mots dans la plupart des dictionnaires, par contre, est liée à leur utilisation courante par les francophones, et est de ce fait plus flexible et dynamique. Je ne suis pas snob ou rigide dans ma réponse ; je ne fais que déclarer que la phrase est grammaticalement incorrecte selon les règles de grammaire du français.