# Des expressions orales abrégées courantes?

Tags: oral, abréviations

En anglais, on peut dire (par exemple) « *One sec* » à la place de « *One second* ».

Y a-t-il des expressions similaires en français?

<sub>À mon avis, cette question doit être un wiki communautaire. (?)</sub>

Comment: À l'oral ou à l'écrit ou les deux ?

Comment: A l'oral particulièrement.

Comment: Excellente question pour maîtriser la (« vraie ») langue de tous les jours. *Drafting…* j'en trouve plein en québecois >_<

Comment: Vous oubliez **C** pour *Tu es c..*.

Comment: À l'oral, @Istao ?!

Comment: Oui je l'ai entendu !

Comment: J'ai une belle deuche...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On en a pas mal sur la page wiki traitant des [apocopes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope), notamment dans la [liste étendue](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie%3aApocopes_en_fran%C3%A7ais).

Une liste courte (car il y en a réellement une quantité énorme), pour donner quelques idées parmi les plus courants :

- prof[esseur]
- métro[politain]
- moto[cyclette]
- photo[graphie]
- télé[vision]
- ...

En revanche, la question concernait-elle spécifiquement les abbréviations par la fin du mot (apocopes, précédemment citées) ? ou peut-on y ajouter tout type d'[amuïssement](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amu%C3%AFssement), comme les [aphérèses](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aph%C3%A9r%C3%A8se_en_fran%C3%A7ais) (*[auto]bus*), même si elles sont un peu moins courantes en français, et qu'en est-il des [syncopes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_%28linguistique%29), [déglutinations](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9glutination), et autres types de [métaplasmes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9taplasme) par suppression ?

Comment: Ah bah voilà, sous pretexte que la réponse est déjà compilée quelque part, ça se permet de faire des réponses-lien ! (:p) Ben… excellent lien, merci ^^ (Et insérer ici des exemples choisis est toujours bien vu.)

Comment: Entièrement de ton avis... je n'ai juste pas encore eu le temps, c'était la réponse *placeholder* en attendant ;-) Ca arrive...

Comment: Bandes de Fastest Frenchies in the Ouest.

Answer (score 1):

- [*Il y a* → « ∅ y'a »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/55/est-il-correct-de-laisser-tomber-le-il-dans-il-y-a?rq=1)
- [*Ne pas faire quelque chose* → « ∅ pas faire quelque chose »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/dans-quelle-mesure-peut-on-omettre-ne?lq=1)

  - Similairement : *je n'en ai pas* → « j'en ai pas »
- *C'est une catastrophe !* → « c'est la *cata* ! »
- *Que dis-tu ?* → *Qu'est-ce que tu dis ?* → « qu'est-ce ∅ tu dis ? »

  - Prononcer [kess'tu dis ?], variable selon les accents.

D'autres suivront…

Comment: Ça me rappelle le fameux *Qu'est ce que tu me racontes là?*.